Is there a way to detect a hump in a linear data?
I have a set of x and y data. When plotted, the data is linear except for a particular section where the data deviates from a straight line, something like a hump. My target is to develop a procedure that identifies the points in the hump (i.e. those points that deviate from the straight line). The attached image shows exactly what I want to achieve.

I have tried fitting a linear trendline to the enter data, calculating the residuals and excluding the section with larger residuals; however, my approach hasn't been very successful. The trendline doesn't seem to pass through the right points. Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Data provided
x = np.array([134, 147, 161, 175, 190, 206, 222, 237, 251, 263, 275, 291, 300, 312, 324, 337, 349, 360, 372, 382]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0.788875116, 0.692846919, 0.605305046, 0.738780558, 0.826074803, 0.871572936, 0.776701184, 
          0.646403726, 0.677606953, 0.615950052, 0.357934847, 0.267171728, 0.217483944, 0.155336037, 
          0.071882007, 0.029383778, -0.008773924, -0.050609993, -0.102372909, -0.148741651])

# Fit linear regression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x, y)
y_pred = model.predict(x)

# Calculate residuals
residuals = y - y_pred
std_dev = np.std(residuals)

# Identify hump points by adjusting alpha
alpha = 2 / 3
threshold = std_dev * alpha
hump_points = np.where(np.abs(residuals) > threshold)[0]

# Visualize
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', label='Data', markersize=6)
plt.plot(x, y_pred, 'r--', label='Fitted Line', linewidth=2)
plt.axhline(0, color='gray', linestyle='--', label='Zero Residual')
plt.scatter(x[hump_points], y[hump_points], color='orange', label='Hump Point', s=100)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Detecting Hump in Data')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# Print hump points
hump_info = [(x[point][0], y[point]) for point in hump_points]



Do you know that the "hump" will always be in the middle and that the first couple and last couple of points will always be clean?

Your trendline doesn’t “pass through the right points” because you fit it on the original dataset (i.e., x and y). You should identify your outliers first, and exclude them before fitting

How do you know that the hump isn't real? Without knowing something about what the data represents and why it should be a linear relationship it is impossible to make any kind of informed comment. The fit you obtained looks quite reasonable to me if you exclude the worst outliers. The gradient either side of the hump is quite different. It is you expectation of the "right" answer that is wrong. Unless you have some other prior information that you haven't shared.

Join the first and last (smallest x and largest x) points with a straight line. At each x value subtract the corresponding point on the line. That gives the excess. But if I looked at that data alone I wouldn’t think “line+hump”, I would probably just think “curved”.

@MartinBrown the data represents some process data where a plot of x and y is supposed to be linear. The presence of a hump depicts some kind of contamination in the data. The task is to detect this hump and skim it off. The first image in my post shows exactly what I am trying to achieve.

The hump represents something real in the data. What earthly use is a line fitted to the data that you thought you ought to have had? If you can be absolutely sure that humps can only be positive then "fit" your initial line to the lowest pair of points at each end of the plot and then use that prediction to select the points to include in your fit.

"some process data where a plot of x and y is supposed to be linear" - why do I always get worried when I hear that?

@lastchance worried? Why?

It presumes that there is a physical reason why x and y should be linearly related. (I note that the first image that you linked is actually on a log scale).

Yes, in the image, the original y-data is plotted in a semilog graph. In my code, I have taken the log of the y data, removing the need for a logarithmic y-scale. So the y data in my code is actually the log of the real y data. I did this so I would fit a linear trendline instead of an exponential trendline. Here is the real y-data: y=[6.15, 4.93, 4.03, 5.48, 6.7, 7.44, 5.98, 4.43, 4.76, 4.13, 2.28,
1.85, 1.65, 1.43, 1.18, 1.07, 0.98, 0.89, 0.79, 0.71]

Your approach is the natural one. And it would work with a bigger line (with same size hump).
But your problem here is that the "hump" is too big (in terms of number of points involved), so the linear regression find a compromise between being good on the line and bad on hump points, and the opposite.
But there is an algorithm that does exactly what you need: fit a line (or a model generally speaking, but here, a line) on your data, but not counting outliers : RANSAC.
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, RANSACRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([134, 147, 161, 175, 190, 206, 222, 237, 251, 263, 275, 291, 300, 312, 324, 337, 349, 360, 372, 382]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0.788875116, 0.692846919, 0.605305046, 0.738780558, 0.826074803, 0.871572936, 0.776701184, 0.646403726, 0.677606953, 0.615950052, 0.357934847, 0.267171728, 0.217483944, 0.155336037, 0.071882007, 0.029383778, -0.008773924, -0.050609993, -0.102372909, -0.148741651])

reg=RANSACRegressor(max_trials=10000, residual_threshold=0.1)
reg.fit(x, y)
a = reg.estimator_.coef_
b = reg.estimator_.intercept_ 
inliers = reg.inlier_mask_
plt.scatter(x[inliers],y[inliers], marker='o')
plt.scatter(x[~inliers],y[~inliers], marker='x')
plt.plot(x, a*x+b)
plt.show()

What RANSAC does is selecting a random subset of your points. Try to fit a line on that subset. Remove the points that are two far from the regressed line, and add (among those that were not selected) those, on the contrary that are closed to the regressed line. And perform a regression, this time, not on a random subset, but on the subset of points that seem not to be outlier.
Then it starts again (because of the random selection, you need several trials to find  line that fits well a subset, preferably the bigger one, of course)
Once that done, you can easily compute the distance between all points and your computed line to find what you want.
Or, even simpler, since RANSAC, in its internal logic also need to discriminate outliers from inliers, you can just hijack RANSAC inlier list

Note that this can be seen as a generalization of what lastchance invented. His algorithm assume that first and last point has to be on the line, when RANSAC makes no assumption at all. So lastchance's method is a bit like RANSAC but with a unique trial, and with intial subset being just first and last point (then, as RANSAC, from the line obtained from this subset, inliers are selected)
Tbh, when I run it several times, I find sometimes solution that wouldn't satisfy you. But that is because, sadly, those solutions are perfectly valid.
See this one for example

Hard to say that it is invalid, and that there exist an objective criteria to rule this solution out. It has found a very good line, once removed some (few) outliers. It is not like your line that pass in the middle of the cloud of points, preferring two half wrong than 1 ok and 1 clearly wrong.
So, unless lastchance's criteria happens to be correct (the first and last points are, no matter what, on the line, or at least, they are not outliers), there are no objective way to tell why the good solution (according to you, and I am sure that from applicative standpoint that is true, but not to mathematical objective criteria — not any you told us about, at least) is the good one, and the other the bad one.
Note that if lastchance's criteria is correct, you can do that with RANSAC too.
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, RANSACRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([134, 147, 161, 175, 190, 206, 222, 237, 251, 263, 275, 291, 300, 312, 324, 337, 349, 360, 372, 382]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0.788875116, 0.692846919, 0.605305046, 0.738780558, 0.826074803, 0.871572936, 0.776701184, 0.646403726, 0.677606953, 0.615950052, 0.357934847, 0.267171728, 0.217483944, 0.155336037, 0.071882007, 0.029383778, -0.008773924, -0.050609993, -0.102372909, -0.148741651])


def isDataValid(XX, YY):
    return (x[0] in XX) and (x[-1] in XX)

reg=RANSACRegressor(max_trials=10000, residual_threshold=0.1, is_data_valid=isDataValid)
reg.fit(x, y)
a = reg.estimator_.coef_
b = reg.estimator_.intercept_ 
inliers = reg.inlier_mask_
plt.scatter(x[inliers],y[inliers], marker='o')
plt.scatter(x[~inliers],y[~inliers], marker='x')
plt.plot(x, a*x+b)
plt.show()

What the point? you may ask, I mean, why then not just use lastchance strategy? The difference is that first and last points are forced then to be inliers (any random subselection that does not include first and last point are invalid), but not right on the line: the algorithm still keeps the liberty to adjust the line, so that first and last points are not exactly on it (while still being "almost" on it) to better fit other points.
With this is_data_valid you are guaranteed that whatever the solution is, it will include as inlier (not necessarily exactly on the line, but that is a good thing, since it let a degree of freedom to the algorithm to better fit the other inliers) the 1st and last point, and wouldn't never end up with my second plot.
You may play with is_data_valid argument to implement other criteria you may think about from an applicative standpoint. Or (but that cost more), with is_model_valid that is the same, but after linear regression, to eject a posteriori some solutions.
Note: the parameter residual_threshold, as you may guess, is exactly the same thing as what you call threshold in your code: tolerated residual error of the linear model. So, you could still use this with your alpha and std_dev, with the same meaning.

Try this one. Note that, without knowing why you would expect a straight line (or a power law if you earlier took logs) in the first place, it may be dubious practice.
For the record, I have: (1) removed the "reshape" on the x data (mainly because I'm not sure what it is supposed to do); (2) detected outliers by first putting the line between first and last points; (3) removed the outliers and then re-fitted the line; (4) turned alpha down a bit.
If you have identified the undesirable data by this method you could remove it and then re-fit the best straight line afterwards. Note Martin Horvath's pertinent comment: "You should identify your outliers first, and exclude them before fitting". This is why I now have a second line created from the data once the initial outliers have been excluded.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# Data provided
x = np.array([134, 147, 161, 175, 190, 206, 222, 237, 251, 263, 275, 291, 300, 312, 324, 337, 349, 360, 372, 382])
y = np.array([0.788875116, 0.692846919, 0.605305046, 0.738780558, 0.826074803, 0.871572936, 0.776701184, 
          0.646403726, 0.677606953, 0.615950052, 0.357934847, 0.267171728, 0.217483944, 0.155336037, 
          0.071882007, 0.029383778, -0.008773924, -0.050609993, -0.102372909, -0.148741651])

# Baseline
y_pred = y[0] + ( y[-1] - y[0] ) / ( x[-1] - x[0] ) * ( x - x[0] )

# Calculate residuals
residuals = y - y_pred
std_dev = np.std(residuals)

# Identify hump points by adjusting alpha
alpha = 1 / 3
threshold = std_dev * alpha
hump_points = np.where(np.abs(residuals) > threshold)[0]
not_hump_points = [ i for i in range( len( x ) ) if i not in hump_points ]

# Regression line to non-outliers
xreduced = [ x[point] for point in not_hump_points ]
yreduced = [ y[point] for point in not_hump_points ]
R = stats.linregress( xreduced, yreduced )
y_pred2 = R.intercept + R.slope * x

# Visualize
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(x, y      , 'o-' , label='Data', markersize=6)
plt.plot(x, y_pred , 'r--', label='Line between endpoints', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y_pred2, 'g:' , label='After removing outliers', linewidth=2)
plt.scatter(x[hump_points], y[hump_points], color='orange', label='Hump Point', s=100)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Detecting Hump in Data')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Output:


EDIT:
The thread owner provided alternative (uncontaminated) data with the following results. (Note that alpha had to be substantially increased to avoid classifying most points as outliers. But 2 standard deviations is a well-known statistical cut-off!) The green dots indicate the final best-fit line. Base of logarithms in the original data not stated, so I just used 10 here.
# Alternative data
x=np.array( [134,147,161,175,190,206,222,237,251,263,275,291,300,312,324,337,349,360,372,382] )
y=np.array( [7.935, 5.896, 4.760, 4.190, 3.678, 3.507, 2.666, 2.109, 1.996, 1.605, 1.383, 1.287, 1.152, 0.955, 0.886, 0.761, 0.696, 0.618, 0.493, 0.434] )
y = np.log10( y )
alpha = 2



I like this. If it were possible in context, I might slightly extend it by doing a linear fit on the first and last couple of data points, but I don't know whether the OP understands the start and end of the "hump".

I wish we knew what the data actually was. The “hump” seems a very large part of it. When I was learning CFD the catchphrase from one of the gurus was “don’t ignore the wiggles - they are trying to tell you something”.

@lastchance, thank you so much for your assistance. To provide more context, the data is reservoir fluid data. It has been observed that a plot of the molecular weight of components in a reservoir fluid against their molar concentration shows an exponential relationship which is linear in a semi-log graph, except for the region where the said reservoir fluid is contaminated. The region where you observe the hump is the contaminated region and the size of the hump depends on the extent of the contamination. For a fluid with lower contamination, the hump will be smaller.

In the data I presented, the x data represents the molecular weights of some components in the reservoir fluid say C10, C11, etc. The y list is their molar concentrations (actually, I have taken the logarithm of their molar concentrations). The task, like I said before, is to identify this hump and screen out the points under the hump. The hump is usually positive, i.e, the contamination usually leads to an overestimation of the molar concentration and not an underestimation.

As per your solution, I can say that the hump usually occurs somewhere in the middle, but I can't say for sure that the first and last points aren't outliers in all cases.

Here is another fluid with minimal contamination (almost zero contamination), x=134,147,161,175,190,206,222,237,251,263,275,291,300,312,324,337,349,360,372,382], y=7.935, 5.896, 4.760, 4.190, 3.678, 3.507, 2.666, 2.109, 1.996, 1.605, 1.383, 1.287, 1.152, 0.955, 0.886, 0.761, 0.696, 0.618, 0.493, 0.434]
Note that I didn't take the logarithm of the molar concentrations in this data.

OK, I edited my post and added the new data (taking log10 of y). You have to increase alpha substantially, or most points would be treated as outliers. Fair enough: your data fits a decent semilog graph (original data exponential in x).
